# creating a sanitizing function

Tags: php

Reading all the posts about sanitizing has left me so confused. I'm creating a blog type of site and need to sanitize user input which will go into a database (user profile information, blog posts, and comments) and certain id's and usernames from GET requests to use queries for information to display.

This is what I've pieced together based on what I've read:

```
function escape($data) {
    global $conn;
    connect();
    $data = $conn->real_escape_string($data);
    $conn->close();
    $data = str_replace(chr(0), '', $data);
    return $data;
}

function sanitize($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = escape($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

The stripslashes confuses me a bit. I know PHP automatically puts those in GET and POST requests and double slashes can be a problem. Should I put addslashes() in the function after stripslashes to make sure it's okay?

For all insert and update statements the inserted values are bound using prepared statements, but all other statements are not prepared (and doing prepared statements on them would not be efficient at this stage in this project for various reasons).

I'd love to get your feedback. Like I said, this is all very confusing!

UPDATE:

I added the $data = str_replace(chr(0), '', $data); to protect against null byte injections. Is that right?

BTW, the only GET requests that go into queries are either ID numbers (which I have a function that removes everything but numbers on) or usernames. I'm using the escape function above to sanitize the username before going into any queries. Is that good enough?

The sanitize function I use on blog posts and profile info which is provided by the user and inserted into a table via a prepared statement.

Comment: @Gordon I disagree. He clearly mentions insert and update statements

Comment: @visevo: Those are not proprietary to MySQL.  Just like SELECT.

Comment: Just insert everything into MYSQL using prepared statement. When you want to output something to the page you can use `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")` and decode it back if you need to insert it back into the db. That should give some protection against SQL Injection. Although there are other vulnerabilities to take care of. (Eg. null bytes injection, XSS,)

Comment: Gordon, the real_escape_string is a mysqli function. And the $conn is a new mysqli (which is in another function). I can see why there's a confusion

Answer (score 1):

```
function cleanInput($input) {

  $search = array(
    '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
    '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
    '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
    '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
  );

    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    return $output;
}    


function sanitize($input) {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            foreach ($input as $var => $val) {
                $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
            }
        } else {
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $input = stripslashes($input);
            }
            $input = cleanInput($input);
            $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: What is `cleanInput()` referring to?

Comment: first you want to check it

Comment: Yes, but there's no function I'm aware of in the standard PHP library called `cleanInput()`. You need to add that method to your answer, otherwise it's a broken solution.

Comment: sorry guy i completely forgot sorryyyyy